# How do I separate the transform from the data for gdaltransform?

Tags: gdal

I have a GeoPDF that is understood by `gdaltransform`. I would like to separate the transform from the data. Is it possible to convert the file to its transform only, in a format that `gdaltransform` can understand?

I would like to convert the PDF to SVG, and then translate screen coordinates from the SVG to latitude, longitude based on the original GeoPDF metadata.

Comment: Could you add some information on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the size, the geotransform, and the projection from `gdalinfo` to convert the coordinates of a pixel on the image to a WGS84 latitude / longitude.

`size`: Scale coordinates from the displayed size to the size expected by `gdal`. `scale_x = size[0] / displayedWidth`. `x = screen_x * scale_x`.

`geotransform`: Six components defining an affine transformation. `(translate_x, scale_x, skew_x, translate_y, skew_y, scale_y) = (e, a, c, f, b, d) = geotransform`.

In matrix form, the geotransform is a matrix multiplication between an affine transform matrix and the augmented coordinates (has an extra `1` at the end) in `size` scale.

```
[ [ a c e ]     [ x ]
  [ b d f ]   * [ y ]
  [ 0 0 1 ] ]   [ 1 ]
```

(This matrix can be multiplied by the scaling matrix for `(scale_x, scale_y`) to go from screen coordinates to projected coordinates in a single operation).

`coordinateSystem`: A WKT string. Long text beginning with `PROJCRS["`... In Python,

```py
from osgeo import ogr, osr

source = osr.SpatialReference() 
source.ImportFromWkt(coordinateSystem)

target = osr.SpatialReference()
target.ImportFromEPSG(4326) # WGS84

transform = osr.CoordinateTransformation(source, target)

x = 10
y = 10

x0 = geotransform[0] + x * geotransform[1] + y * geotransform[2]
y0 = geotransform[3] + x * geotransform[4] + y * geotransform[5]

transform.TransformPoint(x0, y0)  # (x, y, z=0)
```